# 画像を表示させたい

Tags: python

本を見て、練習しているのですが表示されず四苦八苦してます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: コードやエラーメッセージはスクリーンショットだけでなく、テキストをコピーしてそのまま質問に貼り付けて下さい。（正しく貼り付けられれば大抵の場合、スクーンショットは不要になります）
なおその際、投稿に含まれるソースコードや、整形済みのテキストは[選択した上で `{}` ボタンをクリック](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにして下さい。インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。

Comment: [_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "./chap3-back.png"](https://teratail.com/questions/85202)

Comment: 質問者の方が参照されている「本」というのは、おそらく[12歳からはじめる ゼロからの Pythonゲームプログラミング教室](https://www.rutles.net/products/detail.php?product_id=775)で、書籍に記載されているコードが[配布されています](http://www.rutles.net/download/463/)。

Comment: pngファイルでコードを実行してみれば、いけましたので、PicoSushiさんのおっしゃる通りだと思います。

Answer (score 3):

画像を見る限り、11行目の `img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="image/webpy.jpg")` でエラーが発生しているようです。

ここで、 `tkinter`パッケージのドキュメントを参照すると、

> PhotoImage for images in PGM, PPM, GIF and PNG formats. The latter is supported starting with Tk 8.6. 
>   https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.html#images

とのことで、未対応であるJPG形式の画像ファイルを指定しているため、エラーが発生したものと考えられます。そのためJPG画像の代わりに、

- PGM
- PPM
- GIF
- PNG

のいずれかの形式である画像ファイルを用意し、それを `"image/webpy.jpg"` の代わりに指定すると表示できるはずです。